# Add answers at the end of book

Tags: report, exercises, makeindex, enotez

I use the `report` class to write a booklet with exercises for students. Each exercise is defined in a subsection. The structure is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Basics of electrical engineering}
\section{Theory}
Blah blah.
\section{Exercises}
\subsection{Basic complex number calculations}
This is the easy exercise. Find $x$.
\result{$x=5$} % This is what I'm looking for
\subsection{Advanced complex number calculations}
This is the tough exercise. 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]  
\item Find $y$ 
\item Find $z$
\end{enumerate}
\result{a) $y=3$, b) $z=7$}
\end{document}
```

I want to find how to define a command `\result` that will create at the end of the booklet the answers by subsection. So, if the subsections above were 1.2.1-1.2.2, then I should get:

> ### Answers
>
> 1.2.1 x=5
>
> 1.2.2 a) y=3, b) z=7

I believe I should be able to manipulate the `imakeidx` or `enotez` packages to do this, but my Latex skills are too weak.

**Clarification:** I know there are packages to handle questions and answers. However, I want to have questions and full/short solutions. The full solutions only visible to me and the short ones listed at the end of the document as described above. For that reason, I want the `\results` command.

Comment: There a number of packages for this: `exercise`, `xsim`,... https://ctan.org/topic/exercise

Comment: Thanks @cgnieder, seen the packages. I think the requested function should be easy to add to the existing framework rather than having to switch all of my code (hundreds of files) to use one of the other packages. I will do it if there is no other way.

Comment: I still think what you need is already invented by packages like `xsim`. Anyway, there are already loads of questions asking basically the same here on tex.sx: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises?tab=Votes Maybe one of these can give you some starters